# Unable to deploy Android app thru IBM Worklight

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to deploy an Android app with IBM Worklight but it always ends at "Application 'xxx' deployed successfully with environment 'android'" where 'xxx' is my app's name.
Nothing further happens. Not even a error message appears.

I have verified that i am able to run an app on an Android device thru Android Studio if i setup a project from there.

Here are the specifications of the equipment i am using.
I am running IBM Worklight 6.1.0.01 on Eclipse Juno in a Windows 7 Environment.
I have also installed Android Studio (Preview) 0.5.8.
The device i am using to deploy the app is a Samsung GT-N7105 running Android 4.3.

Are there further settings that i need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mean that you are trying to **run** your Worklight app on your Android device using Worklight Studio, in which case you are mistaken.

Worklight Studio **does not** "deploy" the app onto the device.
That is the job of the Google ADT plug-in.

These are steps you need to follow:

1. Create a Worklight project
2. Create a Worklight application
3. Add the Android environment
4. Right-click on the app folder and select Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
5. Right-click on the generated Android project and select Run As > Android application

   - Verify that your device is connected via USB and in development mode, as well as that it appears in the Devices view in Eclipse.

The step you are missing is step 5.
You can choose to either open the generated project in Android Studio (if you have it installed) or to invoke ADT which generates a debug-mode .apk and installs it onto your device.

Step 5 as mentioned above is *not part of Worklight Studio*.

Please review the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training material](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#basics).
Specifically for this question, [Previewing your application on Android](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_03_Previewing_your_application_on_Android.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Hmm...yes, i did execute step 5 but it shows Run As > Android Studio project.
It would then go on to say Running application on android studio and inform me that it has been successfully deployed.
I have Android studio opened as well but i see nothing happening at the Android Studio side.

Comment: You are right clicking on the wrong folder. Not the Worklight android folder, but the Generated android project.

Comment: Yes, that works.
So, what about the Run As > Android Studio portion ? Is that another way to run Android apps ?
Are more settings required for it to work ?

Comment: After you open the project in Android Studio you can simply run it from there. Consult with Google documentation as Android Studio is no a Worklight product (unless you encounter errors which originate from Worklight)